# How to select rows conditionally in a table with JSON data type column in MySQL 5.7.34?

Tags: mysql

I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_products (
    product_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    product_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    product_attributes json NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);
```

One of the row in this table looks like as:

[image]

**product_attributes field:**

```
[
    {
        "site": "site1",
        "categories": [
            "site1 cat1",
            "site1 cat2",
            "site1 cat3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "site": "site2",
        "categories": [
            "site2 cat1",
            "site2 cat2"
        ]
    }
]
```

1. How to select row where `site = site1`?
2. How to select row where `site = site1` and `categories = site1 cat1`?

Comment: use json functions

Comment: this is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/68275284/5193536

Comment: @nbk, No it is different.

Answer (score 0):

Finding it is relatively easy

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tb_products  (
>     product_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
>     product_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
>     product_attributes json NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tb_products
> VALUES (1,'test','[
>     {
>         "site": "site1",
>         "categories": [
>             "site1 cat1",
>             "site1 cat2",
>             "site1 cat3"
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "site": "site2",
>         "categories": [
>             "site2 cat1",
>             "site2 cat2"
>         ]
>     }
> ]')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tb_products 
> WHERE JSON_SEARCH(product_attributes, 'one', 'site1', null, '$[*].site') Is NOT NULL
> AND JSON_SEARCH(product_attributes, 'one', 'site1 cat1', null, '$[*].categories[*]') Is NOT NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> product_id | product_name | product_attributes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
> ---------: | :----------- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>          1 | test         | 5b7b2273697465223a20227369746531222c202263617465676f72696573223a205b2273697465312063617431222c202273697465312063617432222c202273697465312063617433225d7d2c207b2273697465223a20227369746532222c202263617465676f72696573223a205b2273697465322063617431222c202273697465322063617432225d7d5d
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=37dbef1d092fa17f4407c0f53d51f84e)*