# How to add data in a table with JSON data type column in MySQL 5.7.34?

Tags: mysql

I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_products (
    product_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    product_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    product_attributes json NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);
```

One of the row in this table looks like as:

[image]

**product_attributes field:**

```
[
    {
        "site": "site1",
        "categories": [
            "site1 cat1",
            "site1 cat2",
            "site1 cat3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "site": "site2",
        "categories": [
            "site2 cat1",
            "site2 cat2"
        ]
    }
]
```

1. How to add one another object `{"site": "site3", "categories": [...]` to the `product_attributes` column?
2. How to add one another array element `site1 cat4` where `site = site1`?

Comment: 1. [JSON_ARRAY_APPEND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-array-append)  2. do you mean where product_attributes's first element has "site":"site1"?  or where any element has "site":"site1"?

Comment: @ysth I meant where product_attributes's first element has `"site": "site1`. You can tell me about second condition as well.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is hard to handle.

I added the last select because, dbfiddle handles the json datatype not correct but it proves that the new entry exists

I personally recommend using normalizes tables, or switch to mysql 8 JSON table makes some parts easier to handle JSON

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tb_products  (
>     product_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
>     product_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
>     product_attributes json NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tb_products
> VALUES (1,'test','[
>     {
>         "site": "site1",
>         "categories": [
>             "site1 cat1",
>             "site1 cat2",
>             "site1 cat3"
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "site": "site2",
>         "categories": [
>             "site2 cat1",
>             "site2 cat2"
>         ]
>     }
> ]')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tb_products 
> WHERE JSON_SEARCH(product_attributes, 'one', 'site1', null, '$[*].site') Is NOT NULL
> AND JSON_SEARCH(product_attributes, 'one', 'site1 cat1', null, '$[*].categories[*]') Is NOT NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> product_id | product_name | product_attributes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
> ---------: | :----------- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>          1 | test         | 5b7b2273697465223a20227369746531222c202263617465676f72696573223a205b2273697465312063617431222c202273697465312063617432222c202273697465312063617433225d7d2c207b2273697465223a20227369746532222c202263617465676f72696573223a205b2273697465322063617431222c202273697465322063617432225d7d5d
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE tb_products
> SET product_attributes =
> JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(product_attributes,JSON_UNQUOTE(REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH(product_attributes, 'one', 'site1', null, '$[*].site'), '.site', '.categories')), 'site1 cat4')
> WHERE JSON_SEARCH(product_attributes, 'one', 'site1', null, '$[*].site') Is NOT NULL
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tb_products WHERE JSON_SEARCH(product_attributes, 'one', 'site1 cat4', null, '$[*].categories[*]') Is NOT NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> product_id | product_name | product_attributes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> ---------: | :----------- | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>          1 | test         | 5b7b2273697465223a20227369746531222c202263617465676f72696573223a205b2273697465312063617431222c202273697465312063617432222c202273697465312063617433222c202273697465312063617434225d7d2c207b2273697465223a20227369746532222c202263617465676f72696573223a205b2273697465322063617431222c202273697465322063617432225d7d5d
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=187261afe9e3a945de3ee61b7cc76fcb)*